# Optimal way of query and result processing for getting posts by various users

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In our APP users have something similar to the Facebook "wall" page - users can view posts by them or their contacts. Currently we are joining the posts table with the users table directly, however that means that for each post there is also data about the author sent - that is as expected but there could be(and there will be) sometimes more posts by only one user - in this case it just seems to me that we are transferring redundant data.... Are these so minor that we shouldn't care about them? Or is there a way of somehow make MySQL to return referenced table ?(I guess not) Or is it faster to join PHP-side by retrieving the posts first, merging the users' ids and asking DB separately again for the user info and after that just reference from the received posts table to the received user table?

I am sorry for providing no code, but this is more of an theoretical programmatic question :)

Comment: Doing a separate query to get the details will likely be quite a but slower. Yes you are returning data that is duplicated, but unless that data is very large it is likely to be a trivial issue. You might be able to use GROUP_CONCAT to lump several posts but a contact together, depending on how you want things ordered.

Comment: Ok so little data are trivial :) thats enaugh for me :)